# system.web.script name space is not available

Tags: asp.net, dll

i am using visual studio 2010 express edition and when i create a web service i don't get the system.web.script namespace . what is the reason for that.?

Regards,

Sivajith S.

Comment: Did you add System.Web.Extensions dll in References ? Which .net framework your service uses ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who look for a reference to **System.Web.Script** or **System.Web.Script.Serialization**...  Add a reference to **System.Web.Extensions** (4.0) and then add

> using System.Web.Script.Serialization;